# python scripts returns outputs only first result of each page instead of all

Tags: python, scrapy

I am performing a web scraping task where I am outputting all the data into the a json file. If I output the file using `scrapy crawl ufcspider -o quotes.json` from the terminal, I get all the results expected but when I run the script `scrapy crawl ufcspider` only i only get all pages created according to the script but only the first result of each page is outputted into the files instead of all ten outputs.

I also notice that on the terminal all results are being output as expected.

script

```
import scrapy
import json

class ExampleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "ufcspider"

    start_urls = [
        'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/',
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for quote in response.css('div.quote'):

            result = {
                'text': quote.css('span.text::text').get(),
                'author': quote.css('small.author::text').get(),
                'link': 'http://quotes.toscrape.com' + quote.css("span a::attr(href)").get(),
                'tags': quote.css('div.tags a.tag::text').getall()
            }

            yield result

        next_page = response.css("li.next a::attr(href)").get()
        if next_page is not None:
            # next_page = response.urljoin(next_page)
            yield response.follow(next_page, callback=self.parse)

        page = response.url.split("/")[-2]
        filename = f'quotes-{page}.json'
        with open(filename, 'w') as f:
            f.write(json.dumps(result))
            f.close()
        self.log(f'Saved file {filename}')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you override `result` in the for loop.

Replacing with this should work:

```py
import scrapy
import json

class ExampleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "ufcspider"

    start_urls = [
        'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/',
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        results = []
        for quote in response.css('div.quote'):
            result = {
                'text': quote.css('span.text::text').get(),
                'author': quote.css('small.author::text').get(),
                'link': 'http://quotes.toscrape.com' + quote.css("span a::attr(href)").get(),
                'tags': quote.css('div.tags a.tag::text').getall()
            }
            results.append(result)
            yield result

        next_page = response.css("li.next a::attr(href)").get()
        if next_page is not None:
            # next_page = response.urljoin(next_page)
            yield response.follow(next_page, callback=self.parse)

        page = response.url.split("/")[-2]
        filename = f'quotes-{page}.json'
        with open(filename, 'w') as f:
            f.write(json.dumps(results))
            f.close()
        self.log(f'Saved file {filename}')
```